# How to exclude specific attributes when using ldapsearch?

Tags: openldap

I know how to request specific attributes using ldapsearch (by passing them at the end of the cli invocation):

```
ldapsearch -x -D "..." -b "..." sn cn displayName
```

Now, how can I specify only those specific attributes that I don't need ? I currently request all attributes and "grep out" those I don't want/need:

```
ldapsearch -x -D "..." -b "..." | grep -v mail
```

Is there some more elegant way to do this ? I mean, apart from creating a user with no ACL on those attributes ;-).

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an elegant way, but you can do it in a two step approach.

On the first col, use `-A` option to get just the attribute names. Remove from the list the ones you don't care.

On the following calls, use that list of columns. Something like:

```bash
cols=$(ldapsearch -A (...) | tail -n +2 | grep -v "jpegPhoto\|thumbnailPhoto" | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/:/ /g')
ldapsearch (...) $cols
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider this a nasty hack, though it may provide what you want

```
ldapsearch ... | grep -v '^\s'
```

This is based on the output of `ldapsearch 2.4.28` on OSX, and worked with each of the `-L` output options (including none).

The key here is that large entries are continue on the next line with a leading space, so we exclude lines with a leading space.

Comment: I'm afraid the question was precisely about how to *avoit* grepping out the irrelevant attributes. Beside, your solution just truncates multiline attributes and do not change anything about the attribute selection. Thanks anyway.